# grep <> | cat linux commands in shell script

Tags: shell

```
grep "String" war_err.txt > list_of_wlan_common_war.txt | cat
```

This command is passing on command line. But to include in script I have to give `| cat`. can I know what does `| cat` do?

Comment: Why do you have to include it? What happens if you omit it?

Comment: in this case, it doesn't change anything. It's not useful here.

Answer (score 1):

`|` (pipe) symbol links the output of one process to another process input. So using `| cat` should the print the output of prev command ran. Because `cat` commands take the input and print it.

However, in your case it's not doing anything. As you are redirecting the standered output of grep command to text file. So, no further piping is happening.

Comment: But why is my script failing if "| cat" is not given?

Comment: Can you share further info, like the output you expect vs what you are getting?

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the section  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" . We need to see small sample intput , required output from same input, current output and exact text of error msgs. Good luck.